# Решение квадратного уравнения, коэффициенты читаются из файла, результат сохраняется в файл (python)

Tags: python

```py
print('Решаем уравнение a•x²+b•x+c=0')
with open('file.txt') as file:
    x = int(file.readline())
    y = int(file.readline())
    z = int(file.readline())
a=int(x)
b=int(y)
c=int(z)

discriminant = b**2 - 4*a*c
print('Дискриминант = ' + str(discriminant))
if discriminant < 0:
    print('Корней нет')
elif discriminant == 0:
    x = -b / (2 * a)
    print('x = ' + str(x))
else:
    x1 = (-b + discriminant ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - discriminant ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
    print('x₁ = ' + str(x1))
    print('x₂ = ' + str(x2))
```

Код такой, как дальше не знаю, не работает чтение из файла(файл лежит в папке вместе с кодом) Выдает ошибку:

> x = int(file.readline())
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5 2 3'

В текстовом файле написано строчно: `5 2 3`

Answer (score 2):

Методом `file.readline()` вы считываете всю строку (5 2 3) и пытаетесь все эти три числа преобразовать в одно вызовом `int()`

Запишите числа так, чтобы в каждой строке было лишь одно число, либо используйте:

```
x, y, z = map(int, file.readline().split())
```

---

> Можете еще помочь, как сохранить результат в другой файл?

Для этого вам нужно открыть файл в режиме записи (*w*) и использовать метод `write()`.

Например:

```
with open('file2.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file: 
    file.write('x₁ = ' + str(x1))
    file.write('\n') # перенос строки
    file.write('x₂ = ' + str(x2))
```

Указание кодировки (`encoding="utf-8"`)  нужно для правильного отображения символов вроде "₁".

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Comment: Можете еще помочь, как сохранить результат в другой файл?

Answer (score 0):

Итак, как сохранить в другой файл (ответ на комментарий @Илья):

Просто добавьте следующие строчки кода:

```
open_file = open('write.txt', 'w')
open_file.write(*map(str, [x, y, z]))
open_file.close()
```

### Разберём строку 2.

1. Делаем список из `x`, `y` и `z` (в коде `[x, y, z]`
2. Переводим элементы списка в тип `int`  с помощью функции `map`
3. Функцией `*` выводим файл все элементы (стандарт `*` - через пробел)

Помог ответ?